# MessageBox is not showing message on assembler

Tags: assembly, masm, messagebox, masm32

[Screenshot of the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8WJk2.png)

Hi. I Reinstalled  RadASM, but after this MessageBox still did not show the message. It's compiling, and... End! Just standard invoke, all code below:

lab1.Asm

```
.386
.model flat,STDCALL
option casemap :none  ;case sensitive

include lab1.inc

.code
Begin:
    call main
    
invoke ExitProcess,NULL


main proc
    
    Start:
    invoke GetComputerName,addr user_name,addr buflen
    invoke MessageBox,0,addr hello_message,addr hello_title,MB_OK

    ret

main endp

end Begin
```

lab1.Inc

```
include WINDOWS.inc

include user32.inc
include kernel32.inc

includelib user32.lib
includelib kernel32.lib
.data   
  buflen                dd 256 
  hello_title          db ' 
  hello_message   db 'Computer Name: '  
  user_name         db 256 dup (0)
```

Comment: Get [OllyDbg](http://www.ollydbg.de/) and try to signlestep your program in it: `ollydbg.exe lab1.exe`

Answer (score 2):

```
include WINDOWS.inc

include user32.inc
include kernel32.inc

includelib user32.lib
includelib kernel32.lib
.data   
  buflen                dd 256 
  hello_title          db ' 
  hello_message   db 'Computer Name: '  
  user_name         db 256 dup (0)
```

there is an error here, because you started to initialize the variable and did not complete the contents of the variable.

in addition I see a character string. Lines must end with a zero character.

```
hello_title     db 'My title',0
hello_message   db 'Computer Name: ',0
```

[image]

ps
oh yes, I forgot to say, the program is very simple and the main purpose of the program is to determine the username. For signature antiviruses, this is a virus pattern. Therefore, I recommend temporarily disabling the antivirus, or dilute the program with additional features.